# Is there a way to get IE 10+ to fire an event when the overflow of an element changes?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom-events, overflow, internet-explorer-10

I want to test if a div is overflowing. The following code works for webkit and Firefox.

```
var div = $("#myDivWithOverflow")[0];
var OnOverflowChanged = function(){
    alert("OnOverflowChanged");
}

if (div.addEventListener) {
    // webkit
    div.addEventListener ('overflowchanged', OnOverflowChanged, false);
    // firefox
    div.addEventListener ('overflow', OnOverflowChanged, false);
}
```

As far as I can see IE10+ has support for the `addEventListener` method, but does not react on either of the above events.

Is there a way to achieve this in IE?

**Update**: I've created a fiddle which illustrates clearer what I want to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/AyKarsi/sB36r/1/
Unfortunately, the fiddle does not work at all in IE due to some security restrictions

Comment: In chrome and FF it works nicely. (Fixed the " )

Answer (score 1):

Currently, `overflowchanged` are only supported on Webkit browsers.

A work around can be to check for mutation events (notably `DOMAttrModified`) and check if the overflow changed.

```
div.addEventListener("DOMAttrModified", function() {
  // check overflow value
}, false);
```

This won't trigger on screen resize, so it may not do exactly what you're looking for. But it's somewhere you can dig for a solution.

On MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events/Mutation_events
On Microsoft site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn265032(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately IE (and Chrome for ) does not fire an event, when the div starts overflowing. I've updated my question with a fiddle.